# Priority base result from mysql db from two table using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        1 AS rnk,
        `jl`.`jb_id`,
        `jl`.`jb_category`,
        `jl`.`jb_company_name`,
        `jl`.`jb_city`,
        `jl`.`jb_salary`,
        `te`.`emp_mobile`,
        `te`.`emp_name`,
        `jl`.`job_live_date`
    FROM
        `tl_job_listing` AS `jl`
    INNER JOIN `tl_employee` AS `te`
    ON
        `jl`.`jb_city` = `te`.`emp_city` AND `jl`.`jb_education` = `te`.`emp_edu` AND(
            (
                jl.ifgraduate = te.ifgraduate AND jl.ifbtech = jl.ifbtech
            ) OR(
                jl.ifgraduate = te.ifgraduate AND jl.ifpg = te.ifpg
            )
        ) AND `jl`.`jb_exp` = `te`.`emp_exp` AND jl.jb_category = te.prjrole
    WHERE
        (`jl`.`job_live_date` >= '2020-10-25')
    UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
    2 AS rnk,
    `jl`.`jb_id`,
    `jl`.`jb_category`,
    `jl`.`jb_company_name`,
    `jl`.`jb_city`,
    `jl`.`jb_salary`,
    `te`.`emp_mobile`,
    `te`.`emp_name`,
    `jl`.`job_live_date`
FROM
    `tl_job_listing` AS `jl`
INNER JOIN `tl_employee` AS `te`
ON
    `jl`.`jb_city` = `te`.`emp_city` AND `jl`.`jb_education` = `te`.`emp_edu` AND(
        (
            jl.ifgraduate = te.ifgraduate AND jl.ifbtech = jl.ifbtech
        ) OR(
            jl.ifgraduate = te.ifgraduate AND jl.ifpg = te.ifpg
        )
    ) AND `jl`.`jb_exp` = `te`.`emp_exp`
WHERE
    (`jl`.`job_live_date` >= '2020-10-25')
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
    3 AS rnk,
    `jl`.`jb_id`,
    `jl`.`jb_category`,
    `jl`.`jb_company_name`,
    `jl`.`jb_city`,
    `jl`.`jb_salary`,
    `te`.`emp_mobile`,
    `te`.`emp_name`,
    `jl`.`job_live_date`
FROM
    `tl_job_listing` AS `jl`
INNER JOIN `tl_employee` AS `te`
ON
    `jl`.`jb_city` = `te`.`emp_city` AND `jl`.`jb_education` = `te`.`emp_edu` AND `jl`.`jb_exp` = `te`.`emp_exp`
WHERE
    (`jl`.`job_live_date` >= '2020-10-25')
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
    4 AS rnk,
    `jl`.`jb_id`,
    `jl`.`jb_category`,
    `jl`.`jb_company_name`,
    `jl`.`jb_city`,
    `jl`.`jb_salary`,
    `te`.`emp_mobile`,
    `te`.`emp_name`,
    `jl`.`job_live_date`
FROM
    `tl_job_listing` AS `jl`
INNER JOIN `tl_employee` AS `te`
ON
    `jl`.`jb_city` = `te`.`emp_city` AND `jl`.`jb_education` = `te`.`emp_edu`
WHERE
    (`jl`.`job_live_date` >= '2020-10-25')
) tab
ORDER BY
    rnk
```

But it is returning a match in every rnk

[please click on the link to see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rgry.png)

Employee table structure and data

```
CREATE TABLE `tl_employee` (
  `emp_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `emp_language` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `emp_role` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `emp_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `emp_mobile` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `emp_age` int(111) NOT NULL,
  `emp_image` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `emp_idproof` varchar(233) NOT NULL,
  `jb_last_salary` varchar(333) NOT NULL,
  `skill` varchar(333) NOT NULL,
  `ifgraduate` varchar(333) NOT NULL,
  `ifbtech` varchar(333) NOT NULL,
  `ifpg` varchar(333) NOT NULL,
  `other_certificate` varchar(333) NOT NULL,
  `desk_emp_image` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `profile_image_path` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `emp_city` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `emp_state` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `emp_exp` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `emp_edu` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `emp_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `emp_resume` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `emp_pass` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `emp_pas` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `emp_job` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `emp_status` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `register_date` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `inq_on` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `via` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `update_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `prjrole` varchar(1000) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tl_employee` (`emp_id`, `emp_language`, `emp_role`, `emp_name`, `emp_mobile`, `emp_age`, `emp_image`, `emp_idproof`, `jb_last_salary`, `skill`, `ifgraduate`, `ifbtech`, `ifpg`, `other_certificate`, `desk_emp_image`, `profile_image_path`, `emp_city`, `emp_state`, `emp_exp`, `emp_edu`, `emp_email`, `emp_resume`, `emp_pass`, `emp_pas`, `emp_job`, `emp_status`, `register_date`, `inq_on`, `via`, `update_on`, `prjrole`) VALUES
(10208, 'English', 'Job in your city', 'Rohit  Singh', '7011484311', 27, '', 'https://jobsgaar.com/haptik/asstes/employee-resume/125006.png', '6000', 'good driving', 'Not Available', 'Not Available', 'Not Available', 'Not Available', '', '', 'Kolkata', '', '3-4 Years', '10-12th class', 'rajeev@gmail.com', 'https://jobsgaar.com/haptik/asstes/employee-resume/692324.doc', 'f74a3490c6af63551e36a05a954dcd8c', '7011484311', '', 0, 'Mon 7th Dec 2020', '2020-12-07', 'Whatsapp Bot', '2020-12-17 06:14:18', 'Driver');
```

### --
-- Indexes for dumped tables

### --
-- Indexes for table `tl_employee`

```
ALTER TABLE `tl_employee`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `emp_mobile` (`emp_mobile`);
```

JOb Listing table structure and data

### -- Table structure for table `tl_job_listing`

```
CREATE TABLE `tl_job_listing` (
  `jb_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `jb_category` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `jb_company_name` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `company_details` text NOT NULL,
  `company_address` text NOT NULL,
  `jb_city` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `jb_state` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `jb_salary` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `jb_education` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `jb_exp` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ifgraduate` varchar(333) NOT NULL,
  `ifpg` varchar(333) NOT NULL,
  `ifbtech` varchar(333) NOT NULL,
  `other_certificate` varchar(333) NOT NULL,
  `skill` varchar(222) NOT NULL,
  `jb_gender1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `jb_gender2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `jb_gender3` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `jb_contact_person` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `jb_contact_no` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `jb_email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `jb_company_proof` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `jb_posted_by` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `jb_vacancy` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `jb_time` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `call_via` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `job_status` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `reg_date` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `update_job_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `job_from` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `jld` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `jed` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `job_live_date` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `job_expired_date` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `video` text NOT NULL,
  `video_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `joblang` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `via` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `job_valid` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

### --
-- Dumping data for table `tl_job_listing`

```
INSERT INTO `tl_job_listing` (`jb_id`, `jb_category`, `jb_company_name`, `company_details`, `company_address`, `jb_city`, `jb_state`, `jb_salary`, `jb_education`, `jb_exp`, `ifgraduate`, `ifpg`, `ifbtech`, `other_certificate`, `skill`, `jb_gender1`, `jb_gender2`, `jb_gender3`, `jb_contact_person`, `jb_contact_no`, `jb_email`, `jb_company_proof`, `jb_posted_by`, `jb_vacancy`, `jb_time`, `call_via`, `job_status`, `reg_date`, `update_job_date`, `job_from`, `jld`, `jed`, `job_live_date`, `job_expired_date`, `video`, `video_status`, `joblang`, `via`, `job_valid`) VALUES
(429, 'Driver', 'Social beat', '', '', 'Kolkata', '', '8000', '10-12th class', '3-4 Years', 'Not Available', 'Not Available', 'Not Available', 'Not Available', 'good driving', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '9940193825', '', '', '', 'Live', 'Thu 10th Dec 2020', '2020-12-17 06:17:10', '', '1607538600', '1607538600', '2020-12-10', '2020-12-10', '', 0, 0, 'Whatsapp Bot', '');
```

### --
-- Indexes for dumped tables

### --
-- Indexes for table `tl_job_listing`

```
ALTER TABLE `tl_job_listing`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`jb_id`);
```

Comment: @cid can u please answer that ?

Comment: Did you just show us some informations about employes, their name, their salary, their phone number?

Comment: yeah these are the fake entries i have put into my db, but the this is that if employee having perfect match which is rank 1 then it is also going to be match for rank 2,3,4.

Comment: that is why employee named rohit singh coming in rank 1 and 2 both but it should come into rank1 only because it has matched all the fields mentioned in 1st query

Comment: And no I can't answer it, it's pretty unclear to me, there are no explanations, no input sample, no expected output. [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: i will make u clear above code is for finding the perfect match from two tables and show the selected fields, but the issue in the code is that same result is coming in every rank

Comment: You could make it clearer by providing sample data and expected outcome as text (no images please).Also please confirm that each of the separate selects (ie the bits that are being unioned) work as expected.

Comment: yes each of the separate selects worked as expected, the only problem is the same employee gets selected in each select statement

Comment: Not surprised ,you want employees only once with highest rnk? Consider replacing all this with one select and test for rank using case statement which would filter out employee who meets all 4 rnk conditions.

Comment: can u please explain that how to use case statement?or could u just make a query for me so that i can check?

Comment: Please publish table defintions as well as sample data.

Comment: i cannot publish this in the comment, can u please guide me where to publish?

Comment: @P.Salmon pleae check the question i have published tbale definintions as well as data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would join on the minimum requirement -`jl`.`jb_city` = `te`.`emp_city` AND `jl`.`jb_education` = `te`.`emp_edu`- then use case statement to rank

```
SELECT 
     case when ((jl.ifgraduate = te.ifgraduate  AND jl.ifbtech = jl.ifbtech ) OR
                    (jl.ifgraduate = te.ifgraduate   AND jl.ifpg = te.ifpg)) AND 
                      `jl`.`jb_exp` = `te`.`emp_exp` AND 
                      jl.jb_category = te.prjrole    then
                    1
             when ((jl.ifgraduate = te.ifgraduate AND jl.ifbtech = jl.ifbtech) OR
                   (jl.ifgraduate = te.ifgraduate AND jl.ifpg = te.ifpg)) AND 
                    `jl`.`jb_exp` = `te`.`emp_exp` then 
                    2
             when `jl`.`jb_exp` = `te`.`emp_exp` then 
                   3
             else 4
             end as rnk,
    `jl`.`jb_id`,
    `jl`.`jb_category`,
    `jl`.`jb_company_name`,
    `jl`.`jb_city`,
    `jl`.`jb_salary`,
    `te`.`emp_mobile`,
    `te`.`emp_name`,
    `jl`.`job_live_date`
FROM
    `tl_job_listing` AS `jl`
INNER JOIN `tl_employee` AS `te`
ON  `jl`.`jb_city` = `te`.`emp_city` AND `jl`.`jb_education` = `te`.`emp_edu`
WHERE
    (`jl`.`job_live_date` >= '2020-10-25');


+-----+-------+-------------+-----------------+---------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------+
| rnk | jb_id | jb_category | jb_company_name | jb_city | jb_salary | emp_mobile | emp_name     | job_live_date |
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------------+---------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------+
|   1 |   429 | Driver      | Social beat     | Kolkata | 8000      | 7011484311 | Rohit  Singh | 2020-12-10    |
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------------+---------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec)
```

Comment: yeah this works for me but there is still one problem rank1 data is coming in the last i.e rnk1 should be shown in first... can i use ORDER BY rnk?

Comment: Got my result, thank you very ,much for your help